# В консоли linux не пишется символ |

Tags: linux, консоль

Установлен Linux без графического интерфейса, только консоль. Пытаюсь ввести символ | с клавиатуры, нажимая соответствующую кнопку рядом с Enter. Без Shift выводит #, с Shift выводит ~. Попробовал все клавиши с Shift и без. Как можно получить символ |?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианты, которые подходят для любых символов, не только для |:

1. Чтобы посмотреть раскладку нужно ввести команду:

`man ascii`

После чего напечатать нужный символ, например, в моём случае это Alt + 124

2. Можно подключиться через SSH с другого компьютера с другой раскладкой и там напечатать нужный символ.
3. В моём случае проблема была связана с локалью. При установке я выбрал British English, когда при повторной установке выбрал Europe/Moscow проблема исчезла.
4. Для случаев, неправильной раскладки клавиатуры, без переустановки системы и более основательного подхода: [wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration), хоть это и для Arch, но должно применяться практически к любому дистрибутиву.
5. Помимо Arch-Wiki так же могут помочь ссылка на ask-Ubuntu: [Changing TTY keyboard layout on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155424/changing-tty-keyboard-layout-on-a-server) и ссылка на HowtoForge.com: [changing-language-and-keyboard-layout-on-various-linux-distributions](https://www.howtoforge.com/changing-language-and-keyboard-layout-on-various-linux-distributions)